Lower bound on partial Euler Product
Put $R_{t}(x) = \prod_{p > x} \left(1 - p^{-t}\right)^{-1}$. For $x \geq C_{t}$ and $1 < t < 2$, we need to prove that $\log(R_{t}(x)) \geq x^{1-t}$ such that the constant $C_{t} \geq 3$ will depend mostly on $t$. I tried to prove such statement and I get:
$$\log(R_{t}(x)) = - \sum_{p > x} \log (1 - p^{-t}) = \sum_{p > x}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m \cdot p^{m \cdot t}}$$
I need help for any further steps.
Thanks!

Hint: it simplifies matters if you use $\log(1-y)^{-1} > x$ for $0<y<1$.

But $\log(1 - y)$ is negative for $0 < y < 1$ and $x \geq 3$. I didn't get the hint.

That's $\log(1-y)$; what about $\log(1-y)^{-1} = -\log(1-y)$?
